# TS generic type parameters on constructor method

Tags: typescript, generics, types, constructor, keyof

TypeScript allows [marking generics at the method level](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints) to constrain the type of one parameter based on the type of another parameter.

```
class Publisher {
    publish<K extends keyof Channels>(channel: K, payload: Channels[K]) { }
}
```

However, it seems that TypeScript does not support this for the constructor

```
type Events = {
    CastSpell: { caster: string, spell: string },
    Attack: { attacker: string, defender: string },
}

class Achievement {
    constructor<K extends keyof Events>( // Error
        public name: string,
        protected eventLabel: K,
        protected requirement: (eventData: Events[K]) => boolean
    ) { }
}
const achievement = new Achievement(
    'Your first fireball!',
    'CastSpell',
    (event) => event.spell == 'Fireball' // Error
)
```

```
Type parameters cannot appear on a constructor declaration.ts(1092)
```

```
Argument of type '"CastSpell"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'K'.
  '"CastSpell"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be
instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'keyof Events'.ts(2345)
```

I *could* mark the generic at the level of the class, but the constraint I'm attempting to impose is only relevant to the construction of the object rather than an overarching aspect of the class, so a method level generic feels more appropriate.

Is there a way to achieve this? Is there a reason why this is not supported directly?

Comment: you say it's "only relevant to the construction of the object rather than an overarching aspect of the class", but an instance has `eventLabel` and `requirement` properties that depend directly on `K`, whose types are visible from the outside even if their use is prohibited.  And inside, presumably you want to call `requirement` sometime, and if you want that properly typed then anything writing `this.requirement` will need to know about `K`.  If you really want to ask about this (it would be called "existential typing") I'd hope to see a more motivating example; could you [edit] to do that?

Comment: I mean, you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4b14N), but then `this.requirement` is poorly typed because the compiler has forgotten about `K`.  Not sure if that's what you're looking for, and if so, why...

Comment: @jcalz You're right that my example actually does have to do with the overarching essence of the class, given that `eventLabel` is a field that `requirement` as a field depends on. However, in my use case, I don't actually need to store `eventLabel` as an instance field- it will never be used, it only serves to constrain the proceeding `requirement` parameter during construction. I could remove it as a field but leave it as an unused constructor parameter, would [that](https://tsplay.dev/mxkdBN) be a more motivating example?

Comment: No, I still don't get how you're going to do anything useful with `requirement`, which also need depends on `K`; how will you properly call it if you don't know what `K` was?  If you can show me a well-typed program that needs "maybe a `(arg: { caster: string, spell: string })=>boolean)` or maybe a `(arg: { attacker: string, defender: string })=>boolean`" it would help, but I'm skeptical.  For now I'm not comfortable suggesting anything here, other than putting `K` at the class level, which is what the example code is motivating currently.